# How can I connect to MySQL database with android (PHP)?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have tried almost all the code that have been encountered about this issue.

I leave sample code below.

```
//select.php
         <?php
$host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="android";
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
$sqlString = "select * from sample where id='$id'  ";
$rs = mysql_query($sqlString);  
if($rs){
while($objRs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$output[] = $objRs; }
echo json_encode($output); }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

//Main Activity

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        id=e_id.getText().toString();
        select();
        }
        });
        }

        public void select()    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new 
        ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));

        try
        {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/select.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        name=(json_data.getString("name"));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+name,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }        }}
```

I wrote this to.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

//logcat

```
   E/Fail 1: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 E/Fail 2: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
 E/Fail 3: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I try to run the application I get the `INVALID IP ADDRESS` error.
I need some suggestions. What should I try to connect to MySQL database with android (PHP)?

Comment: Use AsyncTask to create your network calls.

Comment: Dont use mysql, it's deprecated. You should use mysqli - http://be2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Exception clearly showing that you are  calling network operation on main thread that's why it is not working . Use async task for network operation and then it will work. From api level 11 android restricted network operations on main thread and if do this it will throw an error network on main thread exception. And you are getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

@Developer_vaibhav I tried the way you said and I got the error again.
mainactivity.class

```
public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

}
public void invokeLogin(View view){
    username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    login(username,password);

}

private void login(final String username, String password) {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            String result = null;

            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://10.0.2.2/login.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute(username, password);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   /* if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }*/

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

@user2508811 I used mysqli.
//login.php

```
    <?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','root1234');
    define('DB','database');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "select * from users where username='$username' and 
    password='$password'";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    if(isset($check)){
    echo 'success';
    }else{
    echo 'failure';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

//logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException
MainActivity$1LoginAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:118)
MainActivity$1LoginAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:64)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I run the application on the emulator and when I click on the button I get the error that stopped the application.

Answer (score 0):

Class inside method? OMG. Make asynctask in isolated .java file and call "new LoginAsync().execute();"

Comment: This does not privede an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @axmed2004 
I've made a mistake of being absent. Thank you for noticing.